# Rails 3 - defining :order using a combination of attributes, while treating the *latest* record differently

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sql-order-by, unobtrusive-javascript

My Application has the following :order requirements:

- Order by the importance (measured by say number of likes) AND
- Order by created_at DESC

So I am currently using the following to define the :order

```
:order => 'model.likes_count DESC, created_at DESC'
```

However, in my views, I create new model entries using AJAX and therefore, I reload the partials where I display the database entries for this particular model and would like to use jQuery effects to (say) highlight the record that was just created.

Now due to the above :order definition, the record just created would not show up as the first one if an older record has greater number of 'likes'.

Is there a way to define an order which takes into account the "latest" record differently and then order the rest of the records as per the defined order? If possible what would be the clean way to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rails API does not have any functionality to treat a newly created record differently.

Your options are:

- Do not select the new record in the query, eg. with `.where("id <> ?",idofnewrecord)`

  You can select the new record in a separate query if required
- Or, select the records as normal, then find the new record in ruby, eg:

  `@newrecord = @records.find{|r|r.id==idofnewrecord}`

  or to delete it from the array of records:

  `@newrecord = @records.delete_if{|r|r.id==idofnewrecord}`

If you don't know the `id`, you may be able to filter it out with some other attribute as well, eg. `created_at`.